# How to prepare a template for a journal

Tags: templates, documentclass-writing, journal

I want to prepare a template for the new launch journal in LaTeX. How to prepare template in LaTeX for a journal? Is there any package for it?
Please help in this regard. sushil

Comment: Write your own document class; there is a [guide on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/clsguide.pdf).

Comment: Hello! I have 3 comments: **(1)** Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. **(2)** You should be more specific, whether the problem is the graphic design of the journal, making compilation of a whole issue fluent and easy-working, etc. The question is too broad to be really answerable. **(3)** Since I'm a journal class author myself, I can tell you that it's a lot of quite complicated work, and if you're not really experienced in LaTeX, you might want/need to contact a professional.

Comment: "template" is *not* the same as "document class".  this question implies that no document class exists for the journal, so presumably both are needed.  if you know of a journal whose design you find appropriate (with modifications), you might take a look at its `.cls` file and see how it was built, whether from scratch, or by loading another class like `article` or `amsart` and building on that.  as tohecz observed, it's not trivial.

Comment: As the other comments say, this is far from trivial and as it stands the question is either too broad or unclear (as we don't really know what you are after).